# How ViewModel is persisted on configuration change

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-components

Looking at the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) documentation, it says:

> In other words, this means that a ViewModel will not be destroyed if
>   its owner is destroyed for a configuration change (e.g. rotation). The
>   new instance of the owner will just re-connected to the existing
>   ViewModel.

How is the ViewModel not destroyed if the activity referencing it is destroyed? and how is it reconnected once we create a new activity?

Comment: hope this [docs](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) will help to clear about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind the scenes a [retained fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) is used. A retained fragment has its state retained across `Activity` re-creation (such as from a configuration change).

See ["Architecture Components Introduction"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrteWKKVyzI) talk from Google IO 2017, where Yigit Boyar talks about `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the talk link, a good answer for my question is on minute 20:00 in the video

Answer (score 3):

The answer is if you use ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YourViewModel.class) to create ViewModel, the library will cache the ViewModel for you. If you create your ViewModel use "new YourViewModel()", the ViewModel will recreate each time when the activity configuration change.
In the ViewModelProviders, it will crate a HolderFragment to add to your activity or your fragment, it's invisible, when the configuration changed, activity destroyed, but the cache is still alive, so next time activity create, the ViewModel will reconnect to it.